# In google colab, How do I save matplotlib image results (from inference output of tensorflow model) to google drive?

Tags: python, tensorflow, matplotlib, google-colaboratory, object-detection

I have created a tensorflow object detection model that detects the position of someone's hand when they are playing the game "rock paper scissors". The model determines if a person's hand is in the "rock" position, the "paper" position, or the "scissors" position.
The model I created is based off of this object detection tutorial: ([found here](https://colab.research.google.com/github/luxonis/depthai-ml-training/blob/master/colab-notebooks/Easy_Object_Detection_With_Custom_Data_Demo_Training.ipynb?authuser=0&pli=1#scrollTo=CG5YUMdg1Po7)). I created the model in google colab and I am running inference on it in google colab. The entire link to the code I use for running inference can be [found here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1SVqEU0MgxpC9n_NklRfkHoNOQqTCawOc?usp=sharing).

I ran inference on the model and received the following results in a matplotlib graph:

([image 1 - rock position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfHZg.png)) ([image 2 - paper position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNu0b.png))

I would like to save these images to by google drive. How would I go about doing this?

Also, below is the code for the cell that is used to run the inferences. This code below gives the output of images like image 1 and image 2, which is shown above.

```
 %cd /content/models/research/object_detection

import numpy as np
import os
import six.moves.urllib as urllib
import sys
import tarfile
import tensorflow as tf
import zipfile

from collections import defaultdict
from io import StringIO
# This is needed to display the images.
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

# This is needed since the notebook is stored in the object_detection folder.
sys.path.append("..")
from object_detection.utils import ops as utils_ops

from object_detection.utils import label_map_util

from object_detection.utils import visualization_utils as vis_util


detection_graph = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph.as_default():
    od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'rb') as fid:
        serialized_graph = fid.read()
        od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
        tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')


label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS)
categories = label_map_util.convert_label_map_to_categories(
    label_map, max_num_classes=num_classes, use_display_name=True)
category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index(categories)


def load_image_into_numpy_array(image):
    (im_width, im_height) = image.size
    return np.array(image.getdata()).reshape(
        (im_height, im_width, 3)).astype(np.uint8)

# Size, in inches, of the output images.
IMAGE_SIZE = (12, 8)


def run_inference_for_single_image(image, graph):
    with graph.as_default():
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            # Get handles to input and output tensors
            ops = tf.get_default_graph().get_operations()
            all_tensor_names = {
                output.name for op in ops for output in op.outputs}
            tensor_dict = {}
            for key in [
                'num_detections', 'detection_boxes', 'detection_scores',
                'detection_classes', 'detection_masks'
            ]:
                tensor_name = key + ':0'
                if tensor_name in all_tensor_names:
                    tensor_dict[key] = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name(
                        tensor_name)
            if 'detection_masks' in tensor_dict:
                # The following processing is only for single image
                detection_boxes = tf.squeeze(
                    tensor_dict['detection_boxes'], [0])
                detection_masks = tf.squeeze(
                    tensor_dict['detection_masks'], [0])
                # Reframe is required to translate mask from box coordinates to image coordinates and fit the image size.
                real_num_detection = tf.cast(
                    tensor_dict['num_detections'][0], tf.int32)
                detection_boxes = tf.slice(detection_boxes, [0, 0], [
                                           real_num_detection, -1])
                detection_masks = tf.slice(detection_masks, [0, 0, 0], [
                                           real_num_detection, -1, -1])
                detection_masks_reframed = utils_ops.reframe_box_masks_to_image_masks(
                    detection_masks, detection_boxes, image.shape[0], image.shape[1])
                detection_masks_reframed = tf.cast(
                    tf.greater(detection_masks_reframed, 0.5), tf.uint8)
                # Follow the convention by adding back the batch dimension
                tensor_dict['detection_masks'] = tf.expand_dims(
                    detection_masks_reframed, 0)
            image_tensor = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')

            # Run inference
            output_dict = sess.run(tensor_dict,
                                   feed_dict={image_tensor: np.expand_dims(image, 0)})

            # all outputs are float32 numpy arrays, so convert types as appropriate
            output_dict['num_detections'] = int(
                output_dict['num_detections'][0])
            output_dict['detection_classes'] = output_dict[
                'detection_classes'][0].astype(np.uint8)
            output_dict['detection_boxes'] = output_dict['detection_boxes'][0]
            output_dict['detection_scores'] = output_dict['detection_scores'][0]
            if 'detection_masks' in output_dict:
                output_dict['detection_masks'] = output_dict['detection_masks'][0]
    return output_dict


for image_path in TEST_IMAGE_PATHS:
    image = Image.open(image_path)
    print(image_path)
    # the array based representation of the image will be used later in order to prepare the
    # result image with boxes and labels on it.
    image_np = load_image_into_numpy_array(image)
    # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
    image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
    # Actual detection.
    output_dict = run_inference_for_single_image(image_np, detection_graph)
    # Visualization of the results of a detection.
    vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
        image_np,
        output_dict['detection_boxes'],
        output_dict['detection_classes'],
        output_dict['detection_scores'],
        category_index,
        instance_masks=output_dict.get('detection_masks'),
        use_normalized_coordinates=True,
        line_thickness=40)
    plt.figure(figsize=IMAGE_SIZE)
    plt.imshow(image_np)
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

plt.show() shows the image, right? to save in google drive just use the following line:

```
plt.savefig('file.png',dpi=300)
plt.show()
```

It'll be saved in the given directory.

Comment: thanks! but how do you save multiple images since the output will have multiple images?